# How many hours a week did the Tolpuddle Martyrs work?

Tags: 19th-century, england, social-history, labour-history

I can find lots of references to the pay rate of the [Tolpuddle Martyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolpuddle_Martyrs) ([originally 10 shillings a week, then reduced to seven shillings and were due to be further reduced to six](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=wNMmCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)) but how many hours a week were they expected to work for it?

Comment: As agricultural labourers, I'd imagine that the length of their working week would vary with the season.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did not find a specific reference to the work hours of the [Tolpuddle Martyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolpuddle_Martyrs) either. It's possible they worked radically unconventional hours, but probably it was no different than the norm at the time. That is to say, **12 hours a day** (less meal time), in the summer. This would've been reduced in the winter in accordance with the much shorter days, so about 8 to 10 hours a day.

> The traditional summer hours for many ordinary labourers in southern English counties had been from 6 a.m. to 6 p.m., with breaks for meals (customarily half an hour for 'breakfast' at mid-morning and an hour for the midday meal). These hours were still found in the 1860s in Northamptonshire, being normal on the estate of Lord Exeter; winter hours were during daylight only.
>
> **<sub>Thirsk, Joan, ed. *The Agrarian history of England and Wales*. Cambridge University Press, 1985.</sub>**

[Dorset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorset) being one of the counties on England's southern coast, presumably the Tolpuddle Martyrs worked something similar.

This is also why around the same time as the Tolpuddle Martyrs, there was a general labour movement demanding an 8 hour work day for 12 hours of pay. Less ambitious unions commonly included 10 or 10.5 hours working day as a major plank of their demands.

> The 'Society for National Regeneration', based in Manchester and headed by Robert Owen and John Fielden, aimed at 'an eight-hour day for twelve hours pay', but folded with the collapse of the Owenite general unions in 1834.
>
> **<sub>Wright, David Gordon. *Popular Radicalism: The Working Class Experience 1780-1880.* Routledge, 2014</sub>**

Comment: Note however that it was often common to work only *half-days* on Wednesday and Saturday. In retail stores this persisted into my youth, with most downtown stores closing at 1:00 pm on Wednesday afternoon until sometime around 1970.

Comment: Assuming 6 days of work per week and 1h30' of pauses for meals per day, that would amount to a working week of 51 hours.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens iirc half day Saturday didn’t exist, nor Wednesday, for UK agricultural labourers. Instead Saint Monday was celebrated regularly.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: My research suggests that the observance of Saint Monday is a **Post** Industrial Revolution custom. This makes much better sense to me because in an agricultural society the cows wait for no-one when they need to be milked, and when the sun shines it is essential to make hay - particularly in a rainy wet climate like England's.